# Split string on only first occurance of character/delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I've been searching all morning for this.

My knowledge of SQL Server is not excellent, and I'm out of answers.

Concrete examples are: `City-Of-Style` or `Part1-Part2`.

I need to split these examples into `City` and `Of-Style` and `Part1` and `Part2`.

I figured out this little piece of code, but it switches part1 and part2 if the string contains a '-'.

```
PARSENAME(REPLACE('sample-string', '-', '.'), 1))
```

Any help on accomplishing this (preferably without a 200 lines function) is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If I understand correctly this will do the job; [Click here for the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/6337)

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(50)= 'City-Of-Style'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@s,0,CHARINDEX('-',@s,0)) AS firstPart,
    SUBSTRING(@s,CHARINDEX('-',@s,0)+1,LEN(@s)) AS secondPart
```

Answer (score 4):

If there are no dashes in the string, you get a blank. The below snippet gives you the first part if there's a dash, otherwise the whole string.

```
DECLARE @TextIn VARCHAR(50)= 'City-Of-Style'
DECLARE @TextOut VARCHAR(500)
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',@TextIn)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(@TextIn,0,CHARINDEX('-',@TextIn,0)) ELSE @TextIn END
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you can use the `split_part` function.

E.g. `cast(split_part(column,'-',1) as text) as new_column`

Input: king-adfad-adfadd
Output: king

Comment: SQL Server v14 split_part is not available. "Not a built-in function"

Answer (score 0):

Building on the previous answers, I offer this as a solution - which provides both the first and last elements. If their is no delimiter found, the last element is empty.

```
DECLARE 
@del varchar(1) = '-',
@TextIn nvarchar(20) = 'City-Of-Style'
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(@del,@TextIn)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(@TextIn,0,CHARINDEX(@del,@TextIn,0)) ELSE @TextIn END AS firstPart,
 CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(@del,@TextIn)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(@TextIn,CHARINDEX(@del,@TextIn,0)+1,LEN(@TextIn)) ELSE '' END AS secondPart
```

Or, if you're working in a stored procedure, you could assign the results to variables:

```
DECLARE 
@del nvarchar(1) = '-',
@firstPart nvarchar(100),
@lastPart nvarchar(100),
@TextIn nvarchar(20) = 'City-Of-Style'
SELECT @firstPart = (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(@del,@TextIn)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(@TextIn,0,CHARINDEX(@del,@TextIn,0)) ELSE @TextIn END),
@lastPart = (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(@del,@TextIn)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(@TextIn,CHARINDEX(@del,@TextIn,0)+1,LEN(@TextIn)) ELSE '' END)

select @firstPart, @lastPart
```