# How to get only the first value before delimeter in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have value like

```
b10F|b3432R|b2134D
```

I need to get only the first value before the pipe:

```
b10F
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you reviewed the numerous string functions available in your specific RDBMS?

Comment: You really need to reveal the exact SQL _database_ you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.).  Every database has its own peculiar string API.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string on only first occurance of character/delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430905/split-string-on-only-first-occurance-of-character-delimiter)

Comment: Even more duplicates can be found with a simple [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Get+first+delimiter+VALUE+sql+server+site:stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 0):

use `mysql query with SUBSTRING_INDEX`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX("b10F|b3432R|b2134D", "|", 1)
```

Comment: Don't use double quotes for string literals.

Comment: Getting this error : 'SUBSTRING_INDEX' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: which SQL your are using? `e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc`

Comment: using SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use this query which uses CHARINDEX function to find the location of first pipe character and then uses LEFT to get data till that position -1

```
 SELECT 
      LEFT(
             'b10F|b3432R|b2134D',
              CHARINDEX('|', 'b10F|b3432R|b2134D' ) -1 
          )AS Output;
```